# What does "up" and "is she" mean?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, sentence-meaning

I read short-story Andrina. I saw these sentences.

> A young woman up at your house? A home help, is she?.

Could anybody explain me why the author wrote "is she". I suppose it's the repeated question, but I am not sure and I do not understand why the author used "is". Also I do not understand the meaning of the "up" in the first sentence. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

When a sentence ends with a comma and 'is he?', 'is she?', 'are they?', 'is it?', or any variant thereof, it is an idiom meaning that the speaker believes the subject of the sentence is described by the first part of the sentence. In this case, the speaker is guessing that the young woman is a 'home help', or maid.